# How can I modify the log format of Katip?

Tags: haskell, logging

I'm trying to use [Katip](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/katip) for logging. I just follow the basic example in [this page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/katip-0.8.3.0/docs/Katip.html). and the log looks like this:

```
[2019-12-03 10:34:28][app.main][Info][yy-Air][PID 45424][ThreadId 7][main:Main app/Main.hs:36:3] Hello Katip
[2019-12-03 10:34:28][app.main.additional_namespace][Warning][yy-Air][PID 45424][ThreadId 7][main:Main app/Main.hs:38:5] Now we're getting fancy
[2019-12-03 10:34:28][app.main.additional_namespace][Error][yy-Air][PID 45424][ThreadId 7] You will never see this!
```

It's too many information to me. So, is there a way to:

1. remove information like *host*, *PID* and *ThreadId*?
2. change the format of its timestamp? Say, I only need something like `[10:34]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a `Scribe` with [**`mkHandleScribe`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/katip-0.8.3.0/docs/Katip-Scribes-Handle.html#v:mkHandleScribe), you can create one with [**`mkHandleScribeWithFormatter`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/katip-0.8.3.0/docs/Katip-Scribes-Handle.html#v:mkHandleScribeWithFormatter) where you pass a *formatter*: a function that decides how to render the content. You can make use of the [**`bracketFormat :: LogItem a => ItemFormatter a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/katip-0.8.3.0/docs/Katip-Scribes-Handle.html#v:bracketFormat) as an example how to implement such formatter.

For example:

```
import Data.Text(pack)
import Data.Time.Clock(UTCTime)
import Data.Time.Format(formatTime, defaultTimeLocale)

import Katip.Scribes.Handle

myTimeFormat :: UTCTime -> Text
myTimeFormat = pack . formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%H:%m"

myFormat :: LogItem a => ItemFormatter a
myFormat withColor verb Item{..} =
    brackets nowStr <>
    brackets (mconcat $ map fromText $ intercalateNs _itemNamespace) <>
    brackets (fromText (renderSeverity' _itemSeverity)) <>
    mconcat ks <>
    maybe mempty (brackets . fromString . locationToString) _itemLoc <>
    fromText " " <> (unLogStr _itemMessage)
  where
    nowStr = fromText (myTimeFormat _itemTime)
    ks = map brackets $ getKeys verb _itemPayload
    renderSeverity' severity =
      colorBySeverity withColor severity (renderSeverity severity)
```

Then you can thus construct a `Scribe` with:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  handleScribe <- mkHandleScribeWithFormatter myFormat ColorIfTerminal stdout (permitItem InfoS) V2
  -- …
```